# List of Visual Studio's Built-In Smart Tags?

Tags: visual-studio, mef, smart-tags

I frequently use the Show Smart Tag shortcut in Visual Studio 2010 (Ctrl + Period) when I want to generate using statements, implement interface methods, generate classes, etc.

I recently introduced this shortcut to my co-workers, and they love it.

Obviously, there is a host of contextual uses for this shortcut, and I feel like I've yet to find them all. Is there a central list of all the smart tags that come built-in with Visual Studio 2010? Or, is there a way for me to actually look at a list of smart tags that Visual Studio 2010 has loaded?

Thanks,
Tedderz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the Visual Studio UI which will display the set of possible smart tags.  You listed MEF in your tags though.  If you are working with a MEF compontent it's very easy to query for this information at runtime.  Simple import all uses of `ISmartTagSourceProvider` and query for the `Name` attribute

```
[ImportMany]
public List<ISmartTagSourceProvider> SmartTagProviders;

void GetNames()
{
  foreach (var provider in SmartTagProviders) { 
    var attrib = (NameAttribute)provider.GetType().GetAttribute(typeof(NameAttribute));
    attrib.Name;
  }
}
```